Docker ABEND after update/upgrade
I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  I was running Docker on a Nvidia Orin with no issues.  I did an apt update then upgrade this morning and apparently messed up my docker installation.  It appears that the update/upgrade (I am leaning to upgrade) wiped out an overlay that was on the SSD.  Below is the error message.  Any guidance would be appreciated, e.g., should I just uninstall and reinstall docker? (Seems drastic)
ptc@orin:~$ docker run -d -it --rm -p 8888 --net=host -v /mnt/ssd:/mnt/ssd cronin/mlbase:version4
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
9e67d3eb58e7effddf79f4f20e4f60aa8cfb10f3c816bd7b8401753bc619019e
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #1: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: time="2024-12-19T10:30:03-05:00" level=info msg="Symlinking /mnt/ssd/docker/overlay2/7dede99aca991da3cbbe0f94db1c71c0e1dc5fc4c420bb6f6d20e6225c6f1a7d/merged/etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json to /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/nvidia_icd.json"
time="2024-12-19T10:30:03-05:00" level=error msg="failed to create link [/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/nvidia_icd.json /etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json]: failed to create symlink: failed to remove existing file: remove /mnt/ssd/docker/overlay2/7dede99aca991da3cbbe0f94db1c71c0e1dc5fc4c420bb6f6d20e6225c6f1a7d/merged/etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json: device or resource busy": unknown.


Does the /mnt/ssd directory contain your Docker storage?  If you don't want either Docker's network isolation or Docker's filesystem isolation, you may find it easier to just run the program directly on the host system.

David,  Many thanks for your feedback.  Yes the docker home directory (& storage) are on the SSD.  The Orin only has 64 gb and that goes quick when you are doing LLMs.  The  SSD has 1 tb.  I have to research the isolation question, I am not sure if I do or do not want isolation of the systems.

Probably mounting a more restricted part of the host filesystem (like just $PWD) will help.  I'd also remove the --net=host option if you can.
